# php 'curl' not working

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to send some value from  '1.php' page to '3.php' page by using 'curl'.

 Heres my code-

**1.php**

```
<?php
$data = array();
$data['first_name'] = 'hello';
$data['last_name'] = 'Thind';
$data['password'] = 'secret';
$data['email'] = 'me@abc.com';
$post_str =''; 
foreach($data as $key=>$val)
{ $post_str .= $key.'='.$val.'&'; } 
$post_str = substr($post_str, 0, -1);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '3.php' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

**3.php**

```
<?php
$host="localhost";       
$dbname="mr"; 
// mysql code for table= create table m(name varchar(10));
$username="";            
$password="";
$con=mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('cannot select db');
if(isset($_POST['first_name'])){
$name=$_POST['first_name'];
$sql="insert into m
values('$name')";
$sq=mysql_query($sql);
echo"ok";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

My problem is **"No data is inserted into database cause no data is transfered to 3.php from 1.php"** .I checked database code in '3.php' by giving some value and that was inserted correctly into database.So code in '3.php' works well.So it seems the code in '1.php' not working. 

 (***Note:*** php_curl.dll is activated in php.ini file. I'm using windows xp professional service pack-2, xampp-win32 version-1.8.1)

 Can anybody please tell me whats wrong there ?

-Thanks.

Comment: Use PDO or MySQLi to access database. mysql_* functions are being deprecated.

Comment: Obviously you did this a long time ago.

But it would seem to me you could alternatively just require('3.php') after setting $_POST vars or do something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '3.php' );`

This requests the URL `3.php`... 
You must give it some "hints" as cURL is an external program that will simply call the URL as is.

**Change it to something like `http://mysite.whatever/3.php`**

---

On a side note, cURL is a command-line utility and it's way easier to debug if used that way. You should first test-it command line and then, if it's workign, implement it on your PHP code.

Mode on cURL here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: Thanks for your help...I changed '3.php' to 'http:// localhost/3.php' and now I got response from '3.php' and thats printed on '1.php'. But no data is inserted into database. Could you please tell me what can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

***RESOLVED*** 
 Heres the complete code (according to Frankie's help)

**1.php**

```
<?php
$data = array();
$data['first_name'] = 'hello';
$data['last_name'] = 'Thind';
$data['password'] = 'secret';
$data['email'] = 'me@abc.com';
$post_str =''; 
foreach($data as $key=>$val)
{ $post_str .= $key.'='.$val.'&'; } 
$post_str = substr($post_str, 0, -1);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/3.php' ); // Heres the change 'http://localhost/3.php' instead of '3.php' . See on Frankie's reply.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

**3.php**

```
<?php
$host="localhost";       
$dbname="mr"; 
// mysql code for table= create table m(name varchar(10));
$username="";            
$password="";
$con=mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('cannot select db');
if(isset($_POST['first_name'])){
$name=$_POST['first_name'];
$sql="insert into m
values('$name')";
$sq=mysql_query($sql);
echo"ok";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Please make notes in your answer noting what you changed from the original code so it's easier to understand.